# Google script .setFormula error with string value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm new to this so please forgive the simple question. I'm trying to insert the following formula into cell E18 of google sheet L2_R1 Final Product:

```
=if(D17="Poor",0,if(D17="Acceptable",1,if(D17="Excellent",2,)))
```

I've gone about it the following way:

```
var sheet4= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("L2_R1 Final Product");

var r2_fpr1_1 = sheet4.getRange("E18");
r2_fpr1_1.setFormula("=if(D18="Poor",0,if(D18="Acceptable",1,if(D18="Excellent",2,)))");
```

This produces the error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line 108, file "Code.gs")
Although I don't think I'm actually missing a )

After going through other posts I've tried the following:

```
var r2_fpr1_1 = sheet4.getRange("E18");
r2_fpr1_1.setFormula("=if(D18=\""+Poor+"\",0,if(D18=\""+Acceptable+"\",1,if(D18=\""+Excellent+"\",2,)))");
```

and

```
var r2_fpr1_1 = sheet4.getRange("E18”) 
r2_fpr1_2.setFormula(`=if(D18="${Poor}",0,if(D18="${Acceptable}",1,if(D18="${Excellent}",2,)))`);
```

Both of those give me the error: ReferenceError: Poor is not defined (line 108, file "Code")

So what am I missing?

Comment: The below answer is correct, but the point is using `\`` : string  template literals or escaping intervening delimiters`\"` or `\'`

Comment: @TheMaster I just noticed that she tried to use literals but she made a typo here: `sheet4.getRange("E18”);`

Comment: @MariosKaramanis The error suggests that it is not a typo in the original script

Comment: yes indeed, that is because the typo is in the `r2_fpr1_1` but then she is calling  `r2_fpr1_2`. I am confused anyways :P

Comment: Burgen, for documentation reasons please accept my answer or provide feedback if my answer didn't work for you so I can help you out.

Comment: @Marios Don't think she's coming back. Last seen was August 21.

Comment: @TheMaster you never know.. She uploaded a picture of hers. Maybe she will come back answering questions in the future :P.

Comment: @Marios Wild dreams you have there... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) instead:

```
var r2_fpr1_1 = sheet4.getRange('E18');
r2_fpr1_1 .setValue(`=if(D17="Poor",0,if(D17="Acceptable",1,if(D17="Excellent",2,)))`)
```

But also [setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula) works just fine:

```
var r2_fpr1_1 = sheet4.getRange('E18');
r2_fpr1_1.setFormula(`=if(D17="Poor",0,if(D17="Acceptable",1,if(D17="Excellent",2,)))`)
```

References:

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)